# Safari private browsing behavior different with redirect with hashtag to another domain

Tags: safari, cross-domain, mobile-safari, hashchange

We have this link below that is on another domain.  When clicked in private tab mode of Safari whether it's a Mac or iPhone does not work correctly and all links after load also seem to double hash change. The double hash change doesn't have a hash value so it returns to the home screen since no hash is available in its value.

This doesn't happen on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari (normal tab).  It also works if you directly put the link in the private safari tab and works correctly.  The only time it doesn't work is a link from another site.

`https://example.com/store?storeorganizationid=31752#/event/registration?eventid=215936`

Any clue on what his behavior maybe happening? This does not seem to be a code issue of any sort.